# How to access a private variable in debugging

Tags: .net, debugging

is there any way to see the values of private varibles while debugging given that that variable is in a class that is compiled to an dll and not possible to edit?

Answer (score 4):

The Visual Studio debugger should already show you those variables when you inspect an instance of the type. Is it not doing so?

Comment: If it's an external DLL which is not in your solution, it won't. Maybe it works when you load debug symbols?

Comment: @dr. evil: It's always worked for me, allowing me to explore the framework class's variables, for example (without any debug symbols available). You generally need to expand the tree view (I can't remember what the exact prompt is) to show you the private variables as well as public properties, but it does work...

Comment: very interesting I had to use reflector addin and decompile framework DLLs to able to see internal fields in debug. Are you sure that you can see external / release DLLs' internal and private fields? Maybe because you enabled source stepping?

Comment: @dr. evil: No, I haven't done anything like that. The debugger just shows me the fields. Which version of VS are you using? I'll confirm it this evening.